# A finite dimensional complex vector space is the direct sum of two subspaces under certain conditions

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional complex vector space, and let $T: V \rightarrow V$ be a linear transformation. Show that $V= W \oplus U$, where $W$ and $U$ are $T$-invariant subspaces and $T|_U: U \rightarrow U$ is nilpotent and $T|_W: W \rightarrow W$ is an isomorphism.

My idea was to use $U=Ker(T)$, $W= Range (T)$. Then I was able to show that both are $T$-invariant. Clearly, we have $T(U)= \{ 0\}$ and $T(W)=W$ is an isomorphism.

Could someone check if my thinking is correctly here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The intesection of the range and the kernel may be nontrivial.

Comment: $T$ is also not guaranteed to restrict to an isomorphism on its range. I don't know what the intended solution is here; you can do it using the Jordan normal form theorem, which I'd guess could be intended from the fact that we are working over $\mathbb{C}$. But actually this statement is true over any field.

Comment: Try $U=\ker (T^n),$ where $n=\dim V.$